# Routing from a react app to get a server side rendered HTML generated from handlebars

Tags: node.js, reactjs, handlebars.js

My react app is running at localhost:3000 and my Node server is running at localhost:5000.

I have a button named **Book** in my React app at the route localhost:3000/. When the button is clicked, i want to render a page(generated by handlebars templating engine) that the route localhost:5000/book renders.

Actually I am very confused right now. I know that localhost:5000/book will render the page. But how do I render that page when clicked the book button from the react code at localhost:3000/.

I know, I can't href to localhost:3000/book, since it would be react's url and not the server's url.
Hence I tried to get the page as a request through axios. But it isn't working. (I know i am doing it wrongly).

The point is how should I route to localhost:5000/book and get it rendered through my react app when I click the book button?

My **Node** code

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Routes
app.get('/book', (req, res) => {
    res.render('book');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `redirect` handler on click of your `book button`

```
redirect = () => {
  window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/book';
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think it is bad practice to switch urls like this. So I have decided not to include server side templating engine. But instead I will go for 100% react code.